# What is $\ln(e^x -4) $, solving for the inverse?

Tags: inverse

What is $\ln(e^x -4) $, solving for the inverse? I know $\ln(e^x)$ is just $x$, but I don't know what to do with the 4.

Comment: Do you want to _simplify_ this expression or do you want to find the inverse function?

Comment: If $y=\ln(e^x-4)$, then $e^x-4=e^y$, so $e^x=e^y+4$ and $x=\ln(e^y+4)$

Answer (score 4):

Take each side to the power of $e$, then modify to solve for $x$:

$$\ln(e^x - 4) = y$$

$$\iff e^x - 4 = e^y$$

$$\iff e^x  = e^y + 4$$

$$\iff x = \ln(e^y + 4)$$